# C# LinkedList<> remove by index

Tags: c#, linked-list

Given a:

```
LinkedList<int> myList;
```

How would I remove an element at `index n`?  I can't seem to find any methods, only ones to remove by value which is no good as this particular list can have duplicate values.

EG:

```
myList.removeAt(n);
```

Comment: That's basically how you can tell that you should not use LinkedList.  Use List instead.

Comment: @HansPassant understood, but in this list I need to be able to move items around as I wish - I thought linked list offered better performance for this.

Comment: @RandRandom hey always learning - thought LinkedList data structure specifically was meant to offer better performance for randomly shuffling items around than a data structure backed by an array

Comment: Its faster for adding and removing, but it is slower at finding a specific index.

Comment: Linked lists can be more efficient for removing nodes that you have an existing reference to (or at the head). Moving nodes around by index is infefficient.

Comment: @RandRandom having 30k rep doesn't make you a master of all trades, I have seen plenty of excellently answered questions from users with less than 1k rep, I have also seen plenty of fairly simple questions from users with more than 50k rep on topics they arent that familiar with. I believe thats why the rep system is fairly flawed.

Comment: I think this link would help.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/582210/3064448

Answer (score 1):

Linked lists have great advantage in speed if you are adding or removing a node you have a existing reference to, but when you don't have a reference the best you can do is walk the list to the index, grab the node, then delete it.

Here is a extension method that does that process. It returns a reference to the removed node in case you want it later to insert to some other list or you are moving it's position within the list.

```
public static class ExtensionMethods
{
    public static LinkedListNode<T> RemoveAt<T>(this LinkedList<T> list, int index)
    {
        LinkedListNode<T> currentNode = list.First;
        for (int i = 0; i <= index && currentNode != null; i++)
        {
            if (i != index)
            {
                currentNode = currentNode.Next;
                continue;
            }

            list.Remove(currentNode);
            return currentNode;
        }

        throw new IndexOutOfRangeException();
    }
}
```