# Remove an element on a given position from a LinkedList

Tags: c#

I try to remove an element after a specified node, code doesn't give me an error but doesn't to its job .

```
public List<int> list;
    public class Node
    {
        public object Cont;
        public Node Next;
    }
    public Node head;

    linkedlist()
    {
        head = null;
    }
    public linkedlist(object value)
    {
        head = new Node();
        head.Cont = value;

    }
    public void removeAfter(int nume1)
    {
        Node currentnode = head;
        int current = 0;
        while (current <= nume1 && currentnode.Next != null)
        {

            currentnode = currentnode.Next;
            current++;

        }
        currentnode = currentnode.Next;
    }
```

I try to remove the element on the "nume1"th position from the LinkedList.
I know c# has a built-in LinkedList but I need to work on this one. The file has more code but I think this is enough to get a proper answer

Comment: To remove the third node, you will need to set the `Next` of the **second** node to the **fourth** node. Can you point us to the line in `removeAfter` where you think you are doing that?

Comment: That is a very good logic there, I agree but can you provide a way (code) of doing that?

Comment: `secondNode.Next = secondNode.Next.Next;` will cut out the third node (`secondNode.Next` is pointing to tne third node, so `secondNode.Next.Next` would be pointing to the fourth node).

Comment: In C# we name our methods `LikeThis()`. Naming them `likeThis()` is java style, please avoid it

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46282199/c-sharp-linkedlist-remove-by-index

Answer (score 0):

In order to remove an item after another item in a singly-linked list, we simply need to set `Item.Next = Item.Next.Next`. This effectively removes the `Node` at `Item.Next` from the list because:

1. If we have a node "first" at index `0`, then it's `Next` will point to "second" at index `1`, and `second.Next` will point to "third" at index `2`
2. So `first.Next.Next` points to "third" at index `2`
3. And setting `first.Next = first.Next.Next` changes the next item for "first" to "third".

For example:

```
class Node
{
    public string Data { get; set; }
    public Node Next { get; set; }
}

class LinkedList
{
    public Node Head { get; private set; }

    public void Add(string data)
    {
        var node = new Node {Data = data};

        if (Head == null)
        {
            Head = node;
        }
        else
        {
            var current = Head;
            while (current.Next != null) current = current.Next;
            current.Next = node;
        }
    }

    public void RemoveAfterIndex(int index)
    {
        if (index < -1) return;

        if (index == -1)
        {
            Head = Head.Next;
            return;
        }

        var current = Head;
        var count = 0;

        while (count < index && current.Next != null)
        {
            current = current.Next;
            count++;
        }

        current.Next = current.Next?.Next;
    }

    public void WriteNodes()
    {
        var current = Head;
        var index = 0;

        while (current != null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(current.Data.PadRight(10) + $" (index {index++})");
            current = current.Next;
        }
    }
}
```

If we wanted to create a list with 10 nodes, and then remove the node after the node at index 3, it might look something like:

```
private static void Main()
{
    var linkedList = new LinkedList();

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        linkedList.Add($"Item #{i + 1}");
    }

    linkedList.WriteNodes();

    var dash = new string('-', 25);
    Console.WriteLine($"{dash}\nCalling: RemoveAfterIndex(3)\n{dash}");

    linkedList.RemoveAfterIndex(3);
    linkedList.WriteNodes();

    GetKeyFromUser("\nDone! Press any key to exit...");
}
```

**Output**

[image: ![![![![enter image description here]

Comment: This post would benefit from a small expl of how this wings and why it doesn't crash if the user asks for removeAfter(9) on a 10 item list. Also, how does the user request removal of the second node?

Comment: @CaiusJard I have an explanation at the top and tried to write the code in a self-describing way. What detail are you looking for? I don't understand why you would think it would crash after calling `RemoveAfter(9)` on a 10-item list. Removing the second node would be `RemoveAfter(1)`. I suppose I could have implemented it to remove the head, but since there is no "zero-th" item, I didn't think it made sense. Perhaps a `RemoveBefore()` method could be used for that.

Comment: Ugh it bugged me enough that I implemented `RemoveAfter(0)` will remove the head.

Comment: I'm still massively puzzled as to how you can have scored most your SO points in C# so you're clearly well versed in it, yet you've reimplemented the OP's "zero based indexing" code as "1 based indexing", when the default convention across all of c# is "zero based indexing"  `¯\_(ツ)_/¯`

Comment: RemoveAfter(0) will be first element. in english, it would be read as 'remove after 0th element' which is the first element. i dont see anyhting wrong with this.

Comment: @CaiusJard I see what you mean. I did that because the OP was talking about the `"nth"` item, which usually means the item at index `n-1` (i.e. the 1st item is at index 0). But I understand the confusion so I changed it to remove at the `index` and renamed the method and parameter to be more clear.

Answer (score 0):

In a single-linked list you remove element `n` by setting `Next` on element `n-1` to element `n+1`.  Since each element has a reference to the following element you need to iterate through the list until you locate element `n`, retaining the previous element as you go.  Then it's just a simple assignment to cut the element from the list.

In code this looks something like:

```
public void RemoveAt(int position)
{
    // reference to current position in list
    Node current = head;

    // check for empty list
    if (current == null)
        return;

    // special case if we're removing the first item in the list
    if (position == 0)
    {
        root = current.Next;
        return;
    }

    // reference to previous position in list
    Node previous = null;

    // scan through the array to locate the item to remove
    for (int i = 0; i < position && current != null; i++)
    {
        // update previous reference
        previous = current;
        // step to next element in list
        current = current.Next;
    }

    if (previous != null && current != null)
    {
        previous.Next = current.Next;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -3):

Where you say this:

```
    currentnode = currentnode.Next;
```

You should consider saying this:

```
    currentnode.Next = currentnode.Next?.Next;
```

If you think about it, to remove the 5th node in a list, you want to make the `.Next` property of the 4th node, point to node 6.  If you're looking at the 4th node, you want its `.Next` (pointing to 5) to be the `.Next.Next` (pointing to 5.pointing to 6) instead.

The `?` after the first `.Next` helps us out if we are at the end of the list. If we are looking at the last item in a list, then `.Next` is null, so calling `.Next.Next` would result in a NullReferenceException. The `?`prevents this by realising the first `.Next` is null and not trying to evaluate the second `.Next` on something that is null, but instead stopping evaluation early and returning a null at that point

It is conceptually equivalent to

```
    currentnode.Next = (currentnode.Next == null ? null : currentNode.Next.Next);
```

It can be done any number of times:

```
a = b.C?.D?.E?.F;
```

If any of `C, D, E` is null, `a` will end up null without causing an exception. You don't need it after `F` because if only the last thing is null no exception occurs - we aren't accessing any method or property of the null `F`

Couple of other points:

Microsoft's own LinkedList has a method of removing nodes based on position, called RemoveAt. It's more useful than RemoveAfter because if can remove the first node in the list, whereas RemoveAfter cannot, unless you take the slightly counterintuitive approach that supplying any index less than the start index will remove the first node (e.g RemoveAfter(-1)). You could create a RemoveBefore or RemoveFirst, but it does add a bit of unnecessary complexity. Generally if taking the academic exercise of re-implementing a class that already exists somewhere in the framework, it's a sensible notion to model your methods on the existing one then it's a good overall fit for "the Microsoft way" in which the rest of the framework is written; fellow developers used to "the Microsoft way" will appreciate it if you're writing a library for them to use

Your naming convention (lowercase first letter for method) is java form, and I did wonder if you were using java but tagged c# for some reason. I'm not sure if null promoting `?` exists in java- if it doesn't the inline-if form given last will also work fine.